# A sock with 28 rep points just deleted my comment?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-comments, sock-puppets

K, so I left a [quick comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160806/how-to-display-specific-data-in-excel-depending-on-parameters-passed-from-a-webpa) to [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856132/sean) who didn't seem to understand how moderator flags worked.

> Moderators are janitors. You flag us when someone throws up in the hallway. We are not professors, tasked with grading answers to questions. If someone provides an unsatisfactory answer, *downvote them, leave a comment, or provide a better answer*. Do **not** flag the answer as "unsatisfactory." There is nothing a moderator can (or should) do about a bad answer. Thanks.

This is what I usually do when I want to make an informal contact with a user for something trivial, as

> Contact[ing] a user directly via private message [is reserved] to address serious behavior problems

Normally, the user replies in another comment directed @Will.  If no more comments are needed, I delete both.  If more are needed, I delete and leave a message requesting the user to ask a question here.

***Anyhow,*** I checked back to see if there was any movement on the question when I saw my comment was deleted.  Wondering if I had gotten flagged (and another mod had deleted my comment to save me from further beclowning myself), I checked to see who deleted it.

[image: Who the hell is Joe?]

[Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887337/joe)?  Who the hell is [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887337/joe)?

> Joe is a brand new StackOverflow member who is about to celebrate the fifteenth (day) anniversary.  A proud member with a stunning reputation of **28**, he enjoys Pina Coladas and getting caught in the rain with his buddy [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856132/sean).  And, surprisingly enough, they not only share the same IP, but also *98%* of the votes [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887337/joe) has cast!

Okay, its obvious Joe is a sock for Sean.  Fine.  I'll leave the merge and suspension for a later date.  But what I really wanna know is...

**How the heck did Joe delete my comment?**

Comment: I can only imagine one thing: more socks. (It would actually be interesting to know how many flags are needed to delete a comment without upvotes.)

Comment: lol @Bill the only thing worse than my admitting I know of that song is you admitting you know *the correct lyrics*.

Comment: It's pretty obvious there are other socks.  Notice sean has at least 2 upvotes on all his answers but one, which has 0, and Joe has 1 less answer upvote than sean has answers.

Comment: I would suggest that nobody merge users until an answer has been found!

Comment: It's actually kind of hilarious to read all of Sean's questions, since he seems to have self-answered every one and taken exactly 2 upvotes for almost all of them.

Comment: Along with user [`john`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/885620/john) who oddly has what would look like much the same voting habits as `Joe`

Comment: @Jeff - funny he started the day before `Joe` as well!

Comment: @JNK Also, check out their favourites, all being sean or one of the other suspected socks.

Comment: So in real life Sean actually has like 100 rep?

Comment: Also, on the whole, his edits look like rep fishing as well with no value or clarity being added or created.

Comment: @Won't - Do you find it ironic that he has 500+ flag weight and you caught him because of a **WAY** invalid flag?

Comment: @JNK: I bet he'd call the cops when somebody steals weed from him.  And, yes, this is yet another reason why I dislike flag weight.

Comment: @won't - My coworkers are now looking at me askance because I appear to be laughing at a 15GB flat file on my other screen.

Comment: Mr Owl, how many flags does it take to get to the center of a tootsie pop?

Comment: @Jeff: One flag (offensive) from me.

Comment: Flag 2 for offensive on Jeff

Comment: so...it's SOCKCEPTION? Instead of a dream within a dream, it's sockpuppets with sockpuppets...

Comment: Flag 3 and it's gone!

Comment: @Shog9 and just like in the commercial 1, 2, *CRUNCH* 3.... 3

Comment: IIRC an earlier iteration of the 10k 'flags' page used to mention the exact number required for autodeletion of comments, but I don't see it there currently

Comment: This also brings up the question of why the suspicious voting algorithm didn't catch this guys (these guy?) earlier.

Comment: @AakashM It's a simple linear progression based on the number of upvotes.

Comment: @Grace: So is it `3+(number of upvotes)`, or is there a factor involved? (And: how do you know this? `:-)`)

Comment: @HendrikVogt `3+floor(upvotes/3)`

Comment: @Hendrik.  Grace knows all.  Never question.

Comment: @Hendrik I remember figuring it out many months ago. There is a factor involved. I don't think it needs to be deliberately vague since the post flagging count is known. So far, though, every *answer* on the subject has been vague so I'm not personally intent on stepping out of line to give the exact specific factor. Nothing to say if someone else wants to venture out on it, though.

Comment: This post has a totally reasonable number of upvotes for a minor question about how comment deletion is represented

Comment: @yoda: And how do _you_ happen to know this? Yedi power? But I'll take your word for it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Grace. It's really strange - I've already asked Jeff Atwood about it (rather explicitly), and he chose to ignore my question.

Comment: @Popular: The two socks are actually listed on the mod tool that helps us find sock puppet accounts, just far down the list.  I have some time off from school after tonight, so I'll go through the list and try to clean it up this week.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Grace told me :)

Comment: Sean seems to have set up his MSO account just after this post was made, so he's probably aware of this discussion.

Comment: So are you going to ban-hammer these users, or what?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Bizanninated.  Been sick/busy.  Which is always awesome.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A sufficient number of flags (in proportion to the number of upvotes on the comment) will automatically delete a comment. The person listed in the "show deleted comments" tool as the deleter is simply the *last* person who flagged. Any other flaggers are not listed, which honestly I find to be a bit odd - honestly it should either be listed as "Community" so as to keep the otherwise maintained anonymity of comment flags, or it should list all such users. Listing just the last is rather awkward.

The conclusion, thusly, is that your comment got sufficient flags (3 flags were needed for your specific comment), the last of which came from Joe.

Comment: Mods being overwhelmed by sockpuppet gangs? Well, now I've seen everything.

Comment: Ninja Socks do exist.  You've just never seen them.

Comment: "Ninja socks," @MTibbits? Come on, now. Don't be ridic _This comment has been deleted by... its author._

Comment: Their fearless leader!

Answer (score 23):

The answer is that he had just enough socks to get it deleted w/o moderator involvement.  We just tested this case on one of my comments on your question and it took exactly 3 flags for it to be autodeleted, and seeing as Sean seems to have 2 socks of Joe and John, it's fairly reasonable to assume that he could remove a comment that you made w/o any other user involvement.

**ADDENDUM:** Also, if what @grace is saying in the comment is the method (ie. linear) this would mean that it's some `(x*number of votes + 3)` for flags for the comment to be deleted.