# No track record, no history (how about mercurial style history for all of us)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, rant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment deletion notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117854/comment-deletion-notification)

I'm unhappy about not being informed when a comment of mine was moderated away and I don't receive a backup of it.

Also, if I don't keep a private record of where I was and what I read, I never remember where I have "participated"; especially not when it was just a comment. I would like to be informed about any evolving threads on the upper left with a special, undistracting color as a sum total. I feel so lost in this space! ...;)

EDIT: today it is 11.02.2013 and again a a comment was deleted of mine which I had still a thought thread tracking in my head. I want to be notified if someone deletes something from me. It is my user contribution. This is not nice towards us users, who nourish this site in the first place. My comment was harmless, I don't know why it was deleted, when it was deleted. It feels like robbery actually, of my time and makes me contribute less often, if any. Can you please at least send a copy to my inbox of things I contribute to the site so I can track down maybe the comment and think.."ah yeah, maybe that was just foolish" or "ok, this was cleared up anyway by common sense" or "don't know why he did that but I probably should stay away from that thread" ? Please.

My comment was like `I tried xyz out and had no results` <-- that is not a troll nor useless. So why are you treating your users that way? *rantinglyfeelingmuchbetter*

Comment: Regarding "I never remember where I have contributed" -- if by that you mean you would like to see a list of comments you made, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164072/panny?tab=activity&sort=comments. Those obviously don't include deleted comments; for that part of the question see the duplicate.

Comment: @balpha oh sorry, you're right! I never discovered them, nice...still, is there a record for upvoted comments also? "Contribution" or maybe more appropriate "participation" for me is  anything I get my hands on which goes beyond scrolling the page and clicking links (which make fantastic history material!)