# Is comment deletion invisible to regular users?

Tags: support, comments

I believe I recently had some comments deleted by a moderator from an answer I wrote and just wondered if there is any way for me to see my own (or others) deleted comments?

I understand from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment) on Meta that aside from a user deleting their own comment, this can also be done by a moderator (either of their own volition, or as a response to flagging of that comment), but didn't realise that there was no audit left to help me realise this had been done - leaving me initially scratching my head and wondering if the comments were even there in the first place!

I'm not disputing that the comments in this particular instance should have been deleted (they involved another user helpfully suggesting a possible issue with my answer, which I then corrected) - hence why I have not included a link to the answer - but it would still be helpful to be able to know that they used to exist.

Plus I can easily imagine situations where the deletion of one or more comments might be objectionable to the commentor, questioner or answerer relevant to the comment - do we just have to trust the moderators here, without any ability to audit what they've deleted (whether that be our own comments, or comments on our own questions/answers)?

Perhaps my answer is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117854/comment-deletion-notification), but that question is several years old, so I hope it's not unacceptable to ask this similar question now to confirm all is still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted comments are only visible to [♦ moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267888/4751173).

In the philosophy of Stack Exchange, comments are [second class citizens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); everything that is worthwhile to be kept **must** be in the questions and answers.

> Comments are *temporary* "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

(emphasis mine)